# U-SQL Table columns are not shown in any ADLA tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-data-lake, u-sql

See the screen below. I have the issue at leaset since Monday (17-Apr)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm what OS you are working on and whether this occurs with the local or remote account?  I cannot reproduce it with my v2.2.6000.0 version of the tools on Win 7 running with the Win 10 runtime fix.

Comment: a) remote azure data lake account b) windows 10 ver 1607 (OS Build 14393.1066) Pro, EN-US c) Visual Studio version 14.0.25431.01 update 2 d) ADLA Tools version 2.2.6000.0

Comment: powershel doesnot return column list too :(. i added one more pic above,

Comment: Thanks again... I forwarded this for investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. It is a regression in the service front-end introduced in the April refresh that has been so far rolled out to the US Central and EU North regions (it does not repro in US EAST 2 since that region is still on the March refresh).

The team is working on a fix and will release it as a hot fix soon.

**UPDATE 2017-Apr-25: The bug has been fixed and the fix has been released.**

Thanks again for reporting!